# How do you specify a windows service in python

Tags: python

I am writing a script that starts and stops windows services in python. So far I've set it to where I can turn on/off any listed service, but I am attempting to have a loop if the listed service is invalid. I created a text file with all listed services on my computer. I am attempting to have create check on whether or not its a real service. My syntax for start/stop services would be

```
choice = input (" Would you like to start or stop a service : ")

if choice == "stop" :

    stopping = 1

   while stopping == 1:

       service_name = input (' Which service would you like to stop : ')

        win32serviceutil.StopService(service_name)

        print ("Service is stopping")

        text = ". . . . . . "

        for char in text:

            sys.stdout.write(char)

            time.sleep(0.5)

        print ( "Service has stopped" )

        break
```

And my attempt at a check would be

```
serviceList = r"C:\Users\ethanm\Desktop\Python Text Files\Windows 
Services List.txt "

inFile = open(serviceList, 'r')

line = inFile.read()

serviceList = line.split()

print (serviceList)

serviceWord = input ("enter a service")

if serviceWord in open (r"C:\Users\ethanm\Desktop\Python Text 
Files\Windows Services List.txt ").read():

    print ("word found")

else:

    print ("no word")
```

Whenever I use the check, it *technically * works, but if I type a character, it gets listed as correct because that character can be found in any of the services. An example would be

```
enter a service : okay

word found
```

And when I enter a normal character

```
enter a service : a

word found
```

I would like the script to be able to tell whether or not it is a valid service, only accepting valid service inputs. An example would be

```
enter a service : spooler

word found

enter a service : anifd

no word

enter a service : aeiou 

no word

enter a service : shpamsvc

word found
```

Comment: have you tried to get all the services' name in the computer and put them in List and then look and see if the input exists in there?

Comment: That is what I have done. I set it up to where I printed all the service names in List, the name is Windows Services List. But yeah the problem continues occuring, I was given an idea to use a batch file to make this simpler and I am trying that out

Comment: Why not use `psutil`?

Comment: that could definitely work as well. I just wanted to work with the win32serviceutil module here.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1:

Store your list of services in an array.

```py
services = ['hello', 'world']
'hello' in services
> True

'he' in services
> False
```

If you have your list of services in a text file that you are reading from, try using the [.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) string method to create an array to work with.

### Method 2:

Add an [exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to your current code.

```py
if input("Would you like to start or stop a service? : ").lower() is "stop":
    while True:
        service_name = input ('Service to stop: ')
        try:
            print ("Service is stopping...")
            win32serviceutil.StopService(service_name)
            print("Service has stopped.")
            break
        except:
            print("Invalid service.")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the idea. This could work if i didnt have 293 services to type out. But I would definitely use this as a last resort type of option where none of the other ideas given to me would work

Comment: the exception works incredibly well thank you very much.